# Pandas Data Cleaning -- Aggregate by Row

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
  lkey  value_x rkey  value_y
0  foo      nan  foo        5
1  foo      nan  foo        8
2  foo        5  foo        5
3  foo        5  foo        8
4  bar      nan  bar        6
5  baz       13  baz        7
```

And I want to clean my data to have the resulting dataframe:

```
  lkey   rkey   value
0  foo   foo        5
1  foo   foo        8
2  foo   foo        5
3  foo   foo        8
4  bar   bar        6
5  baz   baz       13
```

Where value is now a column of arbitrary value based on value_x and value_y (in this case, the maximum). How can I achieve this?

I have looked at agg, groupby, apply, map, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can find max on axis 1.

```
df['value'] = df1[['value_x', 'value_y']].max(1)
```

Or a more generic,

```
df['value'] = df.filter(like = 'value').max(1)
```

You can drop the value_x and value_y using

```
df.drop(['value_x', 'value_y'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Edit: If the values are strings,

```
df[['value_x', 'value_y']].apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x[0]) > len(x[1]) else x[1], axis = 1)
```

Comment: What if value_x and value_y were strings and I wanted to get the value with the maximum length? I tried doing something similar but it didn't work for that.

Comment: if the values are strings, try df[['value_x', 'value_y']].apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x[0]) > len(x[1]) else x[1], axis = 1)